# Closed form of an infinite sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k+p)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I need help on evaluating or finding a closed form for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+p)}$ for which Wolfram Alpha has given me this solution:

[image: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+p)}$]

I tried decomposing the fraction but I'm not sure what this yields for me:

$\frac{1}{k(k+p)}$

$= \frac{1}{pk} - \frac{1}{p(k+p)}$

$= \frac{1}{pk} - \frac{1}{pk} + \frac{1}{k(k+p)}$

$= \frac{1}{pk} - \frac{1}{pk} + \frac{1}{pk} - \frac{1}{p(k+p)}$

$= \frac{1}{pk} - \frac{1}{pk} + \frac{1}{pk} - \frac{1}{pk} + \frac{1}{k(k+p)}$

$=\dots$

and so on.

Comment: That is a closed form expression.

Comment: If $p$ is a positive integer, your first expression is a telescoping sequence, and you get: $\frac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{H_p}{p}$, where $H_p$ is the $pth$ harmonic integer.

Comment: For non-integer $p$ that is about as good as you're going to get; for integer $p$ it telescopes.